# meta name and keywords in only one file

Tags: html, metadata

I have a question about meta name and keywords:
If I have more oages that every page include a file named "_head.php" Can I put metaname and keywords in only this file or is better to put in every page metaname and keywords?
Thanks

Comment: Depends if you want the meta name and keywords to be different on each page I guess. But yes, you can do it.

Comment: Sure, I have the same keywords and meta datafor all pages in this site.

Comment: Added an answer, hopefully the one you were after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not worried about updating the pages separately with different meta content, then it would be beneficial to include the meta tags in an include file. With many pages it would save you a lot of time on updating or tweaking.

Hope this helps!